# MySQL best way to query data from these three tables

Tags: mysql, join

coming to ask your help. Consider the tables below, with the following data:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `jointest`;
CREATE SCHEMA `jointest`;
USE `jointest`;

CREATE TABLE x ( id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT , field VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE z ( id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, field VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE y ( id_x INT, id_z INT, PRIMARY KEY (id_x, id_z) );

INSERT INTO x VALUES (NULL,"Good Morning,"), (NULL,"Good Night,"), (NULL,"Bye");
INSERT INTO z VALUES (NULL, "Dad"), (NULL, "Mom"), (NULL, "Bro!");
INSERT INTO y(id_x, id_z) values(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (3,3);
```

Is there a better solution for querying data from tables x,z? I'd supose something near

```
SELECT x.field, z.field
FROM y
  INNER JOIN x ON (y.id_x = x.id)
  INNER JOIN z ON (y.id_z = z.id)
ORDER BY x.id;
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: A better solution than what? Than the query you're showing?

Comment: What is wrong with your query?

Comment: @DiMono It's my english, man, I should have said `best performance`
@Oliver I don't know if it would be better to start from table x, y or z, using inner, outer, left, right or any other variation I don't know yet ...

Comment: Your query seems fine to me. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: No problems, @Patrick, I just wanted to know about performance (with this kind of situation specifically)
I've suposed it would be better to start from table y, in which I could find the other keys directly.
Now I think I understood what I needed to know (with Matt 's answer). Hope to help others with similar doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a built-in [Query Optimizer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/controlling-optimizer.html), so it doesn't matter in what order you put the tables and joins. Choosing which type of join to use is not a performance issue, but rather depends on what results you wish to return[1](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

It's also important to add indexes on the proper columns to get solid query performance.